# Convert HTML String to PDF byte array in Java

Tags: java, itext

I need to build a function that receives a html document in the form of a string and should return a pdf document as a `byte[]`.

With the following code I can build a pdf document. Ideally, I don't want to generate a pdf document first. Instead, the `byte[]` should be returned without building the pdf document first. How can I prevent the pdf generation and just return the `byte[]`?

I followed this tutorial to get this code so far: https://www.baeldung.com/pdf-conversions-java

```java
public static byte[] convertHtmlToPdfBytes( String htmlString ) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("temp.pdf"));
    document.open();

    InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream(htmlString);

    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, in);
    document.close();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse That duplicate is for C#, this question is for Java. Java doesn't have `MemoryStream`; its equivalent would be `ByteArrayOutputStream` in this usage.

Comment: You can't build a PDF document without building a PDF document. You can, however, write your PDF document to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a `FileOutputStream`, and then convert that `ByteArrayOutputStream` to a `byte[]`.

Comment: Java, C#, it's all the same. Any experienced developer knows what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

I made it possible as follows:

```java
public static byte[] convertHtmlToPdfBytes( String htmlString ) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
    document.open();

    InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream(htmlString);
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, in);
    document.close();

    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you get any java.io.IOException (document has not pages) ?

Comment: I did! Did you manage to solve this issue?